# What is model inferencing - computation or look-up?

Tags: llm, openai, api, text-generation, conversational-ai

I am defining inferencing as querying the LLM. For example, if I goto [ChatGPT](https://chat.openai.com/) and enter text in the text box, then I am inferencing the OpenAI LLM (GPT-x). From the UI's perspective, clearly it is an [REST API call](https://openai.com/product). The following questions are from the point of view of the API implementation.

1. Is the LLM loaded in memory and math computations are done to generate the response (and any other post facto activities)?
2. Does the LLM live separately from the REST API implementation where, the implementation looks-up the weights and applies computation?
3. Is model inferencing a stateful or stateless activity?
4. Considering 1, 2 and 3 how does the REST API auto-scale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. 3. Stateless between two subsequent inferences. 4. Add or remove model instances eg via Kubernetes depending on API usage.

Comment: What a succinct response! Much appreciated, Sir!